# javascript function parameter with object notation

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

What is the differences between

```
function updateSomething(item) {}
```

and

```
function updateSomething({items}) {}
```

?
item variable in the first one can be an object too, why does the second one use an object notation?
When should I use the first one and the latter one?

Comment: I don't think this is valid - function updateSomething({items}) {}

Comment: @Mike It is, now (for the right engine or some transpiler)

Comment: Thanks @DenysSéguret . Didn't know, will read about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is parameter destructuring, from ES2015. In the second case, you're initializing a local variable to the value of the `items` property of the argument.

```
function updateSomething({items}) {
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
function updateSomething(obj) {
     var items = obj.items;
```

Some other examples [here](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#destructuring) and [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_parameter-handling.html).

And from the MDN: [Pulling fields from objects passed as function parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Pulling_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)

Note that this syntax isn't yet available in Edge or Safari (see [compatibility map](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-destructuring,_parameters)) so you might want to use a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Answer (score 2):

The second example is using the shorthand for ES6's parameter destructuring to extract the `item` property from the first parameter, assuming it is an object:

```
function destructure({item}) {
  console.log(item);
}

destructure({item: 3}); // logs "3"
```

The ES5 equivalent would be:

```
function destructure(arg1) {
  var item = arg1.item; // or throw
  ...
}
```

[This blog post by 2ality](http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html) has an excellent writeup of destructuring, parameters, and how they play together.

This will throw an error if the first argument to `destructure` does not have an `item` property.

You can specify the parameter to destructure or combine this with defaults using:

```
function ({foo, bar} = param) {
  console.log(foo, bar); // the rest of param is not available
}

function ({foo, bar = 11} = param) {
  console.log(foo, bar); // bar will be 11 if it was not set in param
}
```

There are a number of variations on this syntax, but it's the counterpart to the object shorthand syntax:

```
const item = 3;
destructure({item}); // creates an object like {item: item}
```